# Invalid response array in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses, why do I get this?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV to build a program to recognize objects. My dataset is CIFAR-10. I've spent 2 days trying to understand the error, but I can't find why this happens. My code is:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
import os, os.path
import csv

labels = []

with open('labels.csv','rb') as lb:
    for row in lb:
        labels.append(row)

os.chdir('train')
#counts the total number of pictures in the "train" folder
nFiles = len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)])



extension = '.png'
images = []
imageLabels = []
trainLabels =[]
trainingDescriptors = []
i = 1
sift = cv2.SIFT()
j = 0
BOW = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(10)

with open('../trainLabels.csv', 'rb') as labels:
    for row in labels:
        imageLabels.extend(row[1])

while i < 5000:
    #Load all images
    #print "loading file " + str(i) + ".png"
    if i%500 == 0:
        print "Loading file " + str(i)
    image = cv2.imread(str(i)+extension,cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    images.append(image.flatten())
    descriptor = np.array([])
    keypoints, descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
    if descriptor != None:
        BOW.add(descriptor)
        trainingDescriptors.extend(descriptor)
    i += 1
    j += 1

dictionary = BOW.cluster()

print "bow dictionary", np.shape(dictionary)

for label in imageLabels:
    if label == 'airplane':
        trainLabels.append(1)
    elif label == 'automobile':
        trainLabels.append(2)
    elif label == 'bird':
        trainLabels.append(3)
    elif label == 'cat':
        trainLabels.append(4)
    elif label == 'deer':
        trainLabels.append(5)
    elif label == 'dog':
        trainLabels.append(6)
    elif label == 'frog':
        trainLabels.append(7)
    elif label == 'horse':
        trainLabels.append(8)
    elif label == 'ship':
        trainLabels.append(9)
    elif label == 'truck':
        trainLabels.append(10)


svm = cv2.SVM()
svm.train(np.array(trainingDescriptors),np.array(trainLabels))
```

The error is in this line:

```
svm.train(np.array(trainingDescriptors),np.array(trainLabels))
```

and the error is:

> error: (-5) Invalid response array in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

Comment: Potentially a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422805/training-svm-algorithm-in-android

The answer there was the array did not match the expected shape, so I would confirm your arrays are the same size.